# Crystal report is not showing any records

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, crystal-reports-2008

In my local pc crystal reports works fine , but on server crystal report is not showing any records or error, What will be the possible issue in it?

Comment: give some more stuff about problem , what is the path you have given ? is it showing any error ? etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got solution, There is versioning mismatch in server and web.config.

I have installed mentioned version on server and bingo.

Thanks to all for showing intrest.

Answer (score 0):

From the description you provided. It seems that the report's data source will need to be refreshed. Try to update the respective data sources and/or datasets in the main report.